# Redirect tr output to sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to replace a string in a file with another string, but before the replacement I need to lowercase the new string before passing it to `sed`.

`echo 'NEWSTRING' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/foo/(my tr output in lowercase)/g' file.txt`

My question is, How we could pass the replacement string as a parameter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed "s/foo/$(echo .. |tr ...)/g" file.txt
```

Comment: I also had to add -i option to replace it in the file.

Comment: Yeah, right, I didn't think of the sed command, was thinking about the other problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs), e.g.:

```
echo 'NEWSTRING' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | xargs -I '{}' sed 's/foo/{}/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/foo/\L'"NEWSTRING"'/'g file
```