# xargs does not preserve leading whitespace in format

Tags: linux, sed, printf, csh, xargs

In Linux C Shell, I need to replace a line in a file with a variable which contains a set of numbers and a string. I am using a combination of printf, xargs and sed to preserve the formatting as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855627/6092285).
This is my code up to now (I couldn't find an easier approach in csh):

```
> echo "  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2     Number of gradient directions" > myfile.txt
> set ndir = `repeat 8 printf '  2'`
> set ndir[1] = 16
> set afmt1 = `repeat 8 printf '%%3d'`
> set afmt = "$afmt1%s"
> printf "$afmt" $ndir "     Number of gradient directions" | xargs -I '{}' sed -i '/Number of gradient directions/c\{}' myfile.txt
```

The result is:

```
> cat myfile.txt
16  2  2  2  2  2  2  2     Number of gradient directions
```

But I need:

```
> cat myfile.txt
 16  2  2  2  2  2  2  2     Number of gradient directions
```

The only issue is that the line loses the %3d format only for the first index of the variable $ndir. I need to preserve this format for the whole line. Is there a more subtle way or a fix to this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-d'\n'` to your `xargs` command:

```
printf "$afmt" $ndir "     Number of gradient directions" | xargs -d'\n' -I '{}' sed -i '/Number of gradient directions/c\{}' myfile.txt
```

The problem is that **`xargs` trims leading whitespace from each input line when using `-I`** , which you can verify as follows:

```
% echo '  A   B  ' | xargs -I {} echo "[{}]"
[A  B  ]
```

Adding option `-d'\n'` deactivates this behavior and causes the entire line to be passed as-is:

```
% echo '  A   B  ' | xargs -d'\n' -I {} echo "[{}]"
[  A  B  ]
```

---

As an aside (not relevant on Linux):

BSD/OSX `xargs` not only trims *both* leading and trailing whitespace with `-I`, it also normalizes line-interior whitespace; Since BSD/OSX `xargs` doesn't support the `-d` option, the following workaround is needed to pass lines as-is (would also work with GNU `xargs`):

```
% echo '  A   B  ' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I {} echo "[{}]"
[  A  B  ]
```

Comment: You are amazing, thanks. I changed the title of my question so others may find their relevant question more easily.

Comment: @S.M.: My pleasure - thanks for updating the question's title.